# Getting started with Valgrind (Invalid Write)

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

it's the first time I use Valgrind and I have a few problems figuring out what's the matter in my easy code written in C. All it does is taking some strings by a file, reversing them and then printing them in another file (or append them, if I pass the program the character "a" as the third argument). Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* reverse(char*,int);

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
    FILE *input, *output; char* s;
    s=malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
    if (argv[3]!=NULL && strcmp(argv[3],"a") == 0) output=fopen(argv[2],"a");
    else output=fopen(argv[2],"w");
    if((input=fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL) {
        perror("File inesistente");
        return -1;
    }
    while(fgets(s,1024,input)!=NULL) {
            s = reverse(s,strlen(s));
            fprintf(output,"%s\n",s);
    }
    free(s);
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
    return 0;
}

char* reverse(char* c,int l) {
    char* buf; int i; buf=malloc((l)*sizeof(char));
    for(i=0; i<l-1; i++) {
        buf[i]=c[l-2-i];
    }
    buf[l-1]='\0';
    return buf;
}
```

And this is what Valgrind tells me:

```
==2768== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2768== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2768== Using Valgrind-3.10.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2768== Command: ./tokfile input.txt output.txt
==2768== 
==2768== Invalid write of size 2
==2768==    at 0x4C2FF2B: __GI_memcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2768==    by 0x4EA6FA3: _IO_getline_info (iogetline.c:105)
==2768==    by 0x4EA5E35: fgets (iofgets.c:56)
==2768==    by 0x40083D: main (tokfile.c:17)
==2768==  Address 0x51fc9d2 is 2 bytes inside a block of size 3 alloc'd
==2768==    at 0x4C2ABA0: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2768==    by 0x40087D: reverse (tokfile.c:27)
==2768==    by 0x40080A: main (tokfile.c:18)
==2768== 
==2768== Invalid write of size 1
==2768==    at 0x4C2FF63: __GI_memcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2768==    by 0x4EA6FA3: _IO_getline_info (iogetline.c:105)
==2768==    by 0x4EA5E35: fgets (iofgets.c:56)
==2768==    by 0x40083D: main (tokfile.c:17)
==2768==  Address 0x51fc9d4 is 1 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==2768==    at 0x4C2ABA0: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2768==    by 0x40087D: reverse (tokfile.c:27)
==2768==    by 0x40080A: main (tokfile.c:18)
==2768== 
==2768== Invalid write of size 1
==2768==    at 0x4EA5EA2: fgets (iofgets.c:64)
==2768==    by 0x40083D: main (tokfile.c:17)
==2768==  Address 0x51fc9d5 is 2 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==2768==    at 0x4C2ABA0: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2768==    by 0x40087D: reverse (tokfile.c:27)
==2768==    by 0x40080A: main (tokfile.c:18)
==2768== 
==2768== Invalid read of size 1
==2768==    at 0x4C2E134: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2768==    by 0x4007FA: main (tokfile.c:18)
==2768==  Address 0x51fc9d3 is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==2768==    at 0x4C2ABA0: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2768==    by 0x40087D: reverse (tokfile.c:27)
==2768==    by 0x40080A: main (tokfile.c:18)
==2768== 
==2768== Invalid read of size 1
==2768==    at 0x4008AB: reverse (tokfile.c:29)
==2768==    by 0x40080A: main (tokfile.c:18)
==2768==  Address 0x51fc9d3 is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==2768==    at 0x4C2ABA0: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2768==    by 0x40087D: reverse (tokfile.c:27)
==2768==    by 0x40080A: main (tokfile.c:18)
==2768== 
==2768== 
==2768== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2768==     in use at exit: 1,044 bytes in 5 blocks
==2768==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 2 frees, 2,180 bytes allocated
==2768== 
==2768== 20 bytes in 4 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==2768==    at 0x4C2ABA0: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2768==    by 0x40087D: reverse (tokfile.c:27)
==2768==    by 0x40080A: main (tokfile.c:18)
==2768== 
==2768== 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==2768==    at 0x4C2ABA0: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2768==    by 0x40074E: main (tokfile.c:10)
==2768== 
==2768== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2768==    definitely lost: 1,044 bytes in 5 blocks
==2768==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2768==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2768==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2768==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2768== 
==2768== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2768== ERROR SUMMARY: 17 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I guess I allocate memory in a wrong way? Are there any problems with fgets? 
Thank you.

Comment: Show us your input.txt file too, not only source and valgrind+memcheck message.

Comment: The line numbers reported by Valgrind don't match up with the code you've presented.  Present code and error messages that go together.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, sorry, It was my edit which changed lines. Reverted.

Comment: @Gixuna, wherever possible, its best to avoid dynamic allocation altogether.  There are times when you do need it, but it looks like you could restructure your code so that it has no such need.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you mean I shouldn't allocate any dynamic space for the string s, but just for the buffer in the routine?

Comment: I'm suggesting that you declare `s` as an *array* of suitable length instead of allocating space for it dynamically, and that your `reverse()` function perform reversal in-place instead of dynamically allocating space for a separate reversed string.

Comment: @JohnBollinger okay, thank you so much. I'll try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the write byte error:

Your reversed string is too short. You have to add 1 to the allocated buffer in `reverse`, because of null-string terminator.

It's not the real valgrind issue (except that the result will be wrong), but since you don't do that, at some point your indexes are wrong. For instance, if you try to reverse an empty string,

- first you `malloc` zero bytes, which is implementation dependent: either it returns `NULL` (then KABOOM when writing into it) or a pointer on something that you should not write into (!) => hardly useful.
- then you do `buf[l-1]='\0';` so you're writing 1 byte before the buffer.

For the second part:

Since `s` has been allocated, doing that:

```
s=reverse(s,strlen(s));
```

gives a memory leak because you're allocating a new string in `reverse` and you return it, overwriting the previous allocated `s` pointer (you lost the reference, but you did not free it)

That explains the "memory lost" messages in the end.

EDIT: as osgx commented, that's also a source of invalid memory write: unless the size of the strings in your file are constant/increasing, the returned buffer may be too short.

I'd suggest that you use in-place reverse algorithm, which would save you the allocation within the `reverse` routine. Also, don't pass `strlen(s)`. You can compute the length from within your routine.

I wrote a quick in-place implementation which avoids `malloc` inside your routine (modifies string and returns it for convenience/print)

```
const char *reverse(char *s)
{
   char temp;
   int i;
   int len=strlen(s);

   for (i=0;i<len/2;i++)
   {
      temp = s[i];
      s[i] = s[len-i-1];
      s[len-i-1] = temp;
   }
   return s;  
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that "Your reversed string is too short"? It is just sized as `strlen()` of original string, is there something wrong here? What is the null string terminator and why strlen doesn't account for it (where is the reference link to the `strlen` definition)?

Comment: Why allocating a new string should give memory leak? It is absence of `free` to create leak, not the malloc call.

Comment: because the old value of `s` is overwritten in the call. and allocating `strlen(s)` doesn't reserve enough space: C strings end with 0 char.

Comment: `malloc`-ing zero bytes is not undefined behavior. It returns a useless, but `free`-able pointer (possibly null).

Comment: The old value of `s` is not only overwritten, the `s` is replaced by some string which can be shorter than original 1024 - byte string. If the second line is longer than first, the `fgets()` will try to access newly allocated array past it end (!)

Comment: @AnT okay but it doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: @osgx good point. That's probably the issue with the write (since we don't have the input data, it's hard to say. Avoiding the malloc in the routine is probably best, then)

Comment: If you allocate 1024 bytes at startup and use the in-place routine I provided you're safe.